# Error: executing.executing.NotOneValueFound: Expected one value, found 0, when I try to multiple a series Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When I tried to do this in Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Column1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Column2': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['NewColumn'] = (df['Column1'] / df['Column2']) * 100
```

I received the error bellow:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/executing/executing.py", line 190, in only
    raise NotOneValueFound('Expected one value, found 0')
executing.executing.NotOneValueFound: Expected one value, found 0
```

Anyone knows what happend ?  Im using Pandas==2.0.3

I was trying to downgrade pandas version but it conflicts with other packages.  I try the method mul() of series but same error.
Even if I did the operation for a line of the dataframe, where it doesn't have null, nor values 0, it generates the same error.

The division operation goes without problems, the problem is when I try to multiply

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is that literally your code?  I cannot duplicate this.  That snippet runs perfectly.  What is the "executing" module?  Are you in an IDE or a debugger of some kind?

Comment: Yes, this code here does not work! I'm trying to run on a jupyter notebook, did you use the same version of pandas?

Comment: I downgraded the pandas version to 2.0.0, it worked!